# How to remove every "/", except the first one on nginx

Tags: python, nginx, url-rewriting, webarchive

FYI: I am trying to replicate the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/*/example.com).

Right now, all the urls I am crawling are being send to the path "D:\website\dateoftoday". My code will remove every "/" from the urls, because you can't save a file with a slash in it. I've created a nginx web server to browse through these files and it works until I try clicking on a Root-Relative path (e.g. `/blog/something`). This is to be expected, because that link does not exist in my path (because its called `blogsomething` and not `/blog/something`).

My question is: how do I remove the "/" in the middle of the url for EVERY url on the web server?

Comment: If you want to keep the first one and remove all other, something like this should work: `'/' + '/blog/something'.replace('/','')`

Comment: @Sefan im not sure you understand what I asked. I want NGINX to remove the "/" not Python. Thanks for your help anyways!